# Condition-check function in SQL SELECT (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL and need to output in SQL SELECT a result of a function that is not uniform.
Namely,

- if column A value is below certain number, I need to output one algebraic correction to column B inside the SELECT statement
- and if it is above, another.

The algebraic corrections are not guaranteed to be "smooth" so I ought to have some IF-like statements.

I would like to do all these inline without e.g. creating custom functions. This is easier to maintain.

What would be the best syntax to achieve this "step" correction inside SELECT?

Comment: We usually use `CASE` statement for that ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this using a `CASE` expression.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN A < threshhold THEN exp_1(B) ELSE exp_2(B) END AS some_col,
FROM yourTable
```

Here you would replace `exp_1(B)` and `exp_2(B)` with the actual expressions involving column `B`.